# VS Code and TypeScript - automatically create missing type properties

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm writing an app in TypeScript using VS Code. When creating an JSON object of a known type, TypeScript will tell me if I've omitted a property that is specified in the type definition. Since typescript knows what is missing, and their datatype, is there no way to have all the properties automatically created with some default value (e.g. "" for string, 0 for number etc.)?

Hopefully this screenshot explain it:
[image]

Since TypeScript knows gold is supposed to have a string attribute `name`, is there not way to tell it to add it? Does anyone know if this is somehow supported in vs code, or if there's an extension that can do it for me?

Comment: Iam not using vs code, but what happens when you type [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgb2QChkzkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAblPOABN6QArlQBG0TgF9iUgDYQwyAPbCAVvQzZIsRCgC8hEsXFA) and hover over the red underlined text - does it not give an option to auto-implement the interface? Also, if you want to initialize properties you can use `null`.

Comment: No, that's exactly what the screenshot is showing (assuming I understood you correctly). It's showing the popup I see when I hover over gold - "No quick fixes available".